# GASでGSSの内容を取得して複数のdiscordチャンネルに送信したいが、値が変わらない

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

**やりたいこと**
GASを使用してGSSの中身を取得してdiscordの複数のチャンネルにメッセージを送りたいと考えています。
for文でうまく回そうと考えたのですが、うまくいかず次のコードだとすべてのチャンネルに同じ出力になります。
どのようにすればそれぞれ違う値を送信することができるでしょうか？

**試したこと**
for文を使って　変数i,jの値を一つずつ増やして、セルを一つずつずらそうとした。

```
function submit(){
  discord(get_value())
};

function get_value() {
  var sheet = get_sheet('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx',0);
  //日付

  var datecoord = sheet.getRange(2,3);
  var date = datecoord.getValue();
  //format
  var formatcoord = sheet.getRange(3, 3);
  var format = formatcoord.getValue();

  //配信時間
  for (let i = 11; i <= 15; i++) {
    var timecoord = sheet.getRange(i,6); 
    var haisintime = timecoord.getValue();
  
    var message = Function('var date = ' + date + '; var haisintime = ' + haisintime + '; return ' + format + ';')();
  
    return message;
  }
  
};

//googleスプレットシート  自動送信
function get_sheet(gss_url,sheet_num) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(gss_url);
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[sheet_num];
  return sheet;
};


function get_sheet2(gss_url,sheet_num) {
  var discord = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(gss_url);
  var sheet2 = discord.getSheets()[sheet_num];
  return sheet2;
};

function discord(message) {
    var sheet2 = get_sheet('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/yyyyyyyy/yyyyyy/yyyyyyy',0);
    for (let j = 2; j <= 6; j++) {
      //webhook
      var webhookcoord = sheet2.getRange(j,8);
      var webhook = webhookcoord.getValue();

    //token
      var tokencoord = sheet2.getRange(j,9);
      var dtoken = tokencoord.getValue();

  　//channel
      var channelcoord = sheet2.getRange(j,7);
      var dchannel = channelcoord.getValue();

    //format
      const url        = webhook;
      const token      = dtoken;
      const channel    = dchannel;
      const text       = message;
      const username   = 'Spidey Bot';
      const parse      = 'full';
      const method     = 'post';

      const payload = {
          'token'      : token,
          'channel'    : channel,
          "content"    : text,
          'username'   : username,
          'parse'      : parse,
      };

      const params = {
          'method' : method,
          'payload' : payload,
          'muteHttpExceptions': true

      };

    response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
    }
    
}
```

**追加コード**
get_value関数のみ

```
function get_value() {
  var sheet = get_sheet('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/xxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxx',0);
  for (let i = 11; i <= 15; i++) {
    //日付
    var datecoord = sheet.getRange(2,3);
    var date = datecoord.getValue();
      //format
    var formatcoord = sheet.getRange(3, 3);
    var format = formatcoord.getValue();

    
    //配信時間
    const range = sheet.getRange(11, 6, 5); 

    /*
    var timecoord = sheet.getRange(i,6); 
    var haisintime = timecoord.getValue();
     */ 
    var message = Function('var date = ' + date + '; var haisintime = ' + haisintime + '; return ' + format + ';')();
  }
  return message;
```

**追加質問**
変数haisintimeが0であったとき、そのチャンネルには送信しないようにしたいと考えています。
get_value()の配信時間のところでhaisintimeをif、elseで0である場合は
Noneとして、discord()で送らないメッセージを飛ばそうとしたのですがどうもうまくいきません。
アドバイスを頂けるとありがたいです。

```
function submit(){
  discord()
};

function get_value() {
  var sheet1 = get_sheet('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/xxxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxx',0);
    
    var datecoord = sheet1.getRange(2,3);
    var date = datecoord.getValue();
      //format
    var formatcoord = sheet1.getRange(3, 3);
    var format = formatcoord.getValue();

    
    //配信時間
    var messages_array = []; // initialize
    //var lastRow = sheet1.getLastRow()-10;
    //console.log(lastRow);
  for (let i = 11; i <= 16; i++) {
    var timecoord = sheet1.getRange(i,6); 
    var haisintime = timecoord.getValue();
    if (haisintime == 0) {
      var message = 'None'
      } else {
      var message = Function('var date = ' + date + '; var haisintime = ' + haisintime + '; return ' + format + ';')();
    }
    messages_array.push(message); // push
  }
  return messages_array; // return
    
  
};


function get_sheet(gss_url,sheet_num) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(gss_url);
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[sheet_num];
  return sheet;
};

function get_sheet2(gss_url,sheet_num) {
  var discord = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(gss_url);
  var sheet2 = discord.getSheets()[sheet_num];
  return sheet2;
};

function discord(message) {
    var sheet2 = get_sheet2('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/yyyyy/yyyy/yyyyy',0);

    var messages = get_value();  // call get_value() at here

    var lastRow2 = sheet2.getLastRow();  //最終行取得
    
    for (let j = 2; j <= lastRow2; j++) {
      //webhook
      var webhookcoord = sheet2.getRange(j,2);
      var webhook = webhookcoord.getValue();

    //token
      var tokencoord = sheet2.getRange(j,3);
      var dtoken = tokencoord.getValue();

  　//channel
      var channelcoord = sheet2.getRange(j,1);
      var dchannel = channelcoord.getValue();

    //format
      const url        = webhook;
      const token      = dtoken;
      const channel    = dchannel;
      const textdata       = messages[j-2];
      if (textdata == 'None') {
        continue;
      }
      else {
        const text = testdata;
      }
      
      const username   = 'Spidey Bot';
      const parse      = 'full';
      const method     = 'post';

      const payload = {
          'token'      : token,
          'channel'    : channel,
          "content"    : text,
          'username'   : username,
          'parse'      : parse,
      };

      const params = {
          'method' : method,
          'payload' : payload,
          'muteHttpExceptions': true

      };

    response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `get_value()` 関数内の for loop で `return message;` としているので、ループが初回で終わってしまっています。ループ内で `return` せずに配列に全ての message を入れておいて、その配列を返す様にすればよいのではないでしょうか。

Comment: { }に値を全て入れるということでしょうか？　@metropolis

Comment: 連想配列でも構いませんが、インデックスが整数値の通常の配列でもよいかと思います。

Comment: 追加で質問にget_value()関数を書いたのですが、配列を使ってループを回すやり方がよくわかりません。GASは初心者ですので具体的にどのようなコードであればできるかを教えていただけると幸いです。 @metropolis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### 追加質問に対する回答

推測になりますが、`get_value()` 内の for loop の内部で `var message = ...` としているために、変数 `message` のスコープが `if` 文の内側に限定されているのではないかと思います。なので、以下の様に変更します。ここで、`haisintime` が `0` の場合には `None` という文字列ではなく空文字列(`''`)がセットされる事になります(もちろん、`None` をセットしても構いません)。

```
    //配信時間
    var messages_array = []; // initialize
    //var lastRow = sheet1.getLastRow()-10;
    //console.log(lastRow);
  for (let i = 11; i <= 16; i++) {
    var timecoord = sheet1.getRange(i,6); 
    var haisintime = timecoord.getValue();
    var message = '';
    if (haisintime > 0) {
      message = Function('var date = ' + date + '; var haisintime = ' + haisintime + '; return ' + format + ';')();
    }
    messages_array.push(message); // push
  }
```

次に `discord()` ですが、early return に変更します。

```
function discord(message) {
                     :

    var sheet2 = get_sheet2('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/yyyyy/yyyy/yyyyy',0);
    for (let j = 2; j <= lastRow2; j++) {
      // skip when message is empty
      const textdata = messages[j-2];
      if (textdata === '') {
        continue;
      }

      //webhook
      var webhookcoord = sheet2.getRange(j,2);
      var webhook = webhookcoord.getValue();
                   :

      const payload = {
          'token'      : token,
          'channel'    : channel,
          "content"    : textdata, // textdata is not empty
          'username'   : username,
          'parse'      : parse,
      };
```

##### 当初の質問に対する回答

変更部分は `submit()` と `get_value()` と `discord()` になります。

- `discord()` 内で `get_value()` を呼び出す
- `get_value()` はメッセージの配列を返す
- `discord()` 内の for loop でメッセージをセット、インデックスの差異を調整

> GASは初心者ですので具体的にどのようなコードであればできるか

私も GAS でプログラムを書いたことはありませんので、推測で変更しました。動作確認はしていませんので想定通りに動作しない場合にはそちらで修正して下さい。

```
function submit(){
  discord()
};

function get_value() {
  var sheet = get_sheet('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx',0);
  //日付

  var datecoord = sheet.getRange(2,3);
  var date = datecoord.getValue();
  //format
  var formatcoord = sheet.getRange(3, 3);
  var format = formatcoord.getValue();

  //配信時間
  var messages_array = []; // initialize
  for (let i = 11; i <= 15; i++) {
    var timecoord = sheet.getRange(i,6); 
    var haisintime = timecoord.getValue();
  
    var message = Function('var date = ' + date + '; var haisintime = ' + haisintime + '; return ' + format + ';')();
 
    messages_array.push(message); // push
  }
 
  return messages_array; // return
};

function discord() {
    var sheet2 = get_sheet('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/yyyyyyyy/yyyyyy/yyyyyyy',0);

    var messages = get_value();  // call get_value() at here

    for (let j = 2; j <= 6; j++) {
      //webhook
      var webhookcoord = sheet2.getRange(j,8);
      var webhook = webhookcoord.getValue();

    //token
      var tokencoord = sheet2.getRange(j,9);
      var dtoken = tokencoord.getValue();

    //channel
      var channelcoord = sheet2.getRange(j,7);
      var dchannel = channelcoord.getValue();

    //format
      const url        = webhook;
      const token      = dtoken;
      const channel    = dchannel;
      const text       = messages[j-2]; // offset value equals to 2
      const username   = 'Spidey Bot';
      const parse      = 'full';
      const method     = 'post';

      const payload = {
          'token'      : token,
          'channel'    : channel,
          "content"    : text,
          'username'   : username,
          'parse'      : parse,
      };

      const params = {
          'method' : method,
          'payload' : payload,
          'muteHttpExceptions': true
      };

    response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
    }
}
```

Comment: 無事望むような実行の形になりました。 @metropolis

Comment: 追加で申し訳ありませんが、質問を本文に追加しました。アドバイスを頂けると嬉しいです。@metropolis

Comment: 回答を書いてみましたが、前回と同様に動作確認ができないので、そちらで試してみて下さい。